# Best practice of keeping web3 connection alive with AWS Lambda

Tags: web3.py, python, aws

I am using a python flask app on AWS Lambda to serve my application, and i want to use web3 for some queries.
Because lambda is inherently functional, i want to somehow keep my web3 connection alive and avoid a connection attempt for each query.

What would be the best practice for this task?

Example code -

```
from web3 import Web3
from binascii import hexlify
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/check", methods=['GET'])
def check_address():
    address = request.args.get('address')
    if not Web3.isAddress(address):
        error = f'{address} is not a valid Ethereum address.'
        return make_response(jsonify(error=error), 400)
    if not hexlify(web3.eth.get_code(address)):
        error = f'{address} is not a deployed contract.'
        return make_response(jsonify(error=error), 400)
    message = f'{address} is a deployed contract!'
    return jsonify(message=message)
```